# Goodness of fit with MATLAB and chi-square test

Tags: matlab, statistics, curve-fitting

I would like to measure the goodness-of-fit to an exponential decay curve. I am using the `lsqcurvefit` MATLAB function. I have been suggested by someone to do a [chi-square test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test).

I would like to use the MATLAB function `chi2gof` but I am not sure how I would tell it that the data is being fitted to an exponential curve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `chi2gof` function tests the null hypothesis that a set of data, say `X`, is a random sample drawn from some specified distribution (such as the exponential distribution).

From your description in the question, it sounds like you want to see how well your data `X` fits an exponential decay function. I really must emphasize, this is **completely different** to testing whether `X` is a random sample drawn from the exponential distribution. If you use `chi2gof` for your stated purpose, you'll get meaningless results.

The usual approach for testing the goodness of fit for some data `X` to some function `f` is [least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_squares), or some variant on least squares. Further, a least squares approach can be used to generate test statistics that test [goodness-of-fit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goodness_of_fit), many of which are distributed according to the chi-square distribution. I believe this is probably what your friend was referring to.

**EDIT:** I have a few spare minutes so here's something to get you started. DISCLAIMER: I've never worked specifically on this problem, so what follows may **not** be correct. I'm going to assume you have a set of data x_n, n = 1, ..., N, and the corresponding timestamps for the data, t_n, n = 1, ..., N. Now, the exponential decay function is y_n = y_0 * e^{-b * t_n}. Note that by taking the natural logarithm of both sides we get: ln(y_n) = ln(y_0) - b * t_n. Okay, so this suggests using OLS to estimate the linear model ln(x_n) = ln(x_0) - b * t_n + e_n. Nice! Because now we can test goodness-of-fit using the standard R^2 measure, which matlab will return in the `stats` structure if you use the `regress` function to perform OLS. Hope this helps. Again I emphasize, I came up with this off the top of my head in a couple of minutes, so there may be good reasons why what I've suggested is a bad idea. Also, if you know the initial value of the process (ie x_0), then you may want to look into constrained least squares where you bind the parameter ln(x_0) to its known value.

Comment: Thanks for the idea to linearize the model, but the slight problem here is my model is this: `y_n = k + y_0*e^(-b*t_n)`. With the `k` term you can no longer linearize using logarithms. But perhaps I should have mentioned that I am using `lsqcurvefit` to do fitting. Isn't there any way to get a statistical measure of goodness-of-fit.

Comment: In your situation you can still use R^2 as a heuristic measure of goodness of fit. The wikipedia link is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination). Since you are able to estimate the parameters of your model using `lsqcurvefit` you are also able to estimate the residual terms (the deviation of y_n around the estimated line). Thus you have everything you need to calculate the R^2 (it is just 1 minus (variance of y_n / variance of ehat_n)). For anything more fancy than this, I'm afraid I'd have to do some serious research of my own to help you :-) Cheers.